# object out of range error for no reason

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing the code below in VBA macro excel, my problem is that I get the object our of range error in the line (107, col 10) and I don't know why.
the line I get the error

```
  .Range(.Cells(x, "A"), .Cells(x, "AC")).Select
```

my code is below

```
    Sub MRP()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
      Dim wks As Worksheet
      Dim OPwks As Worksheet
      Dim MRPwks As Worksheet
      Dim OPDwks As Worksheet
      Dim DbCwks As Worksheet

      Dim x As Long
      Dim p As Integer, i As Long, q As Long
      Dim a As Integer, m As Integer, k As Long

      Dim rowRange As Range
      Dim colRange As Range

       Dim LastCol As Long
       Dim LastRowOPwks As Long
       Dim LastRowMRPwks As Long
       Dim LastRowDBCwks As Long

       Set MRPwks = Worksheets("MRP")
       Set OPwks = Worksheets("OpenPOsReport")
       Set DbCwks = Worksheets("CompDB")

       Set wks = ActiveSheet
       Worksheets("OpenPOsReport").Activate

       LastRowMRPwks = MRPwks.Cells(MRPwks.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
       LastRowOPwks = OPwks.Cells(OPwks.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
       LastRowDBCwks = DbCwks.Cells(DbCwks.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        'Set rowRange = wks.Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

        'For m = 8 To LastRow
        'Cells(m, "N") = 0
        'Next m

        For i = 2 To LastRowDBCwks
            p = 0
            For q = 8 To LastRowOPwks

             If DbCwks.Cells(i, "V") = 0 Then k = 0 Else: k = p / Cells(i, "V")

             If OPwks.Cells(q, "A") = DbCwks.Cells(i, "A") Then
             If OPwks.Cells(q, "D") = 0 Or OPwks.Cells(q, "B") < 1 / 1 / 18 
      Then GoTo Nextiteration Else

                If (OPwks.Cells(q, "C") + DbCwks.Cells(i, "C")) >= 
       (DbCwks.Cells(i, "F") + k) Then
                OPwks.Cells(q, "N").Value = 1
                OPwks.Range(Cells(q, "A"), Cells(q, "N")).Select
                With Selection.Interior
               .Pattern = xlSolid
               .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
               .Color = 255
              .TintAndShade = 0
              .PatternTintAndShade = 0
              End With
              Else
                p = p + OPwks.Cells(q, "D").Value
                    OPwks.Cells(q, "N").Value = 0
                    OPwks.Range(Cells(q, "A"), Cells(q, "O")).Select
                    With Selection.Interior
                   .Pattern = xlNone
                   .TintAndShade = 0
                  .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With

                End If
             End If
     Nextiteration:
             Next q
          Next i

     'For q = 8 To LastRow
     '    If Cells(q, "N") = 1 Then
     '              End If
     '              Next

        With MRPwks
     For x = 5 To LastRowMRPwks
            If .Cells(x, "AC").Value > 0 Then
                .Range(.Cells(x, "A"), .Cells(x, "AC")).Select
                With Selection.Interior
               .Pattern = xlSolid
               .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
               .Color = 255
              .TintAndShade = 0
              .PatternTintAndShade = 0
               End With
               End If
              If .Cells(x, "AC") = 0 Then
            .Range(.Cells(x, "A"), .Cells(x, "AC")).Select
                    With Selection.Interior
                   .Pattern = xlNone
                   .TintAndShade = 0
                  .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                End With
            End If

            Next x

            End With

     End Sub
```

I dont know why I get the Object out of range error in the first part of the code.

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` at the top? Might just be a typo in a variable name somewhere.

Comment: There's no such error as "object out of range".

Comment: Error on line 107 column 10?  Erm.... the code doesn't have line numbers so if I paste into Notepad++ before I removed the white space then line 107 is the final `Next X` in the code?  Should `Then GoTo Nextiteration Else` and `(DbCwks.Cells(i, "F") + k) Then` be on lines by themselves?  None of the worksheet variables seem to be defined.  Could you have a read of [MCVE] please.

Comment: When you get the errror, hit "Debug" - which line is highlighted?  Line numbers are  no real use here...

Comment: When I paste your code in to Notepad (and after correcting for two misplaced line breaks) there are only 107 lines of code. You need to better identify which line raises the error.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I got the error on  .Range(.Cells(x, "A"), .Cells(x, "AC")).Select

Comment: @J.Fox where is this option exactly cant find it

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook so where I get the error is on .                         .Range(.Cells(x, "A"), .Cells(x, "AC")).Select

Comment: @TimWilliams sorry for my lack of experience, the line I get the error is  .Range(.Cells(x, "A"), .Cells(x, "AC")).Select

Comment: @DavidZemens I get the error on line  .Range(.Cells(x, "A"), .Cells(x, "AC")).Select

Comment: My guess is that you really don't mean `OPwks.Cells(q, "B") < 1 / 1 / 18`. Note that `1/1/18` is the number 1/18 not the date January 1, 2018.

Comment: I@JohnColeman just fixed the date with the date (1/1/18) or will fix the it with the value of 43101 which is the number value of 1/1/18 but thats not where I get the error

Comment: what value of `x` when the error occurs? (though I'm not sure if that will be useful to know, the line of code doesn't look like it would throw that error)

Comment: @DavidZemens dont know how to debug it for me to show the value of x. but when I just run that part in another macro it runs ok, but in this it gives me that error

Comment: You need to learn how to debug. Start here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/debuggingvba.aspx

Comment: @ShahinTaghikhani Doesn't look like it was the issue in this instance, but you just type in `Option Explicit` above your `Sub` declaration and it basically forces you to declare every variable used in the macro. It's Best Practice™ to use it all the time but ymmv

Comment: @J.Fox thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

You have `Worksheets("OpenPOsReport").Activate` in your code, then you try to select  `.Range(.Cells(x, "A"), .Cells(x, "AC")).Select` on `MRPwks` which is not active at that time. This is not possible.

Change your code to

```
With MRPwks
    For x = 5 To LastRowMRPwks
        If .Cells(x, "AC").Value > 0 Then
            With .Range(.Cells(x, "A"), .Cells(x, "AC")).Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 255
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
        If .Cells(x, "AC") = 0 Then
            With .Range(.Cells(x, "A"), .Cells(x, "AC")).Interior
                .Pattern = xlNone
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If

    Next x

End With
```

It is not neccessary to select the range first.

Comment: I deleted Worksheets("OpenPOsReport").Activate part and again got "method select of object range failed" error

Comment: You did not understand. I did not tell you to remove `.activate`. I did tell you to remove select.

Comment: Ok ur answer was half loaded

Comment: Even in my first half loaded part I did not tell you to remove `.activate`. You still do not understand what you are doing when activating a sheet first and then selecting a range on another sheet.

Comment: I got your point, am reading Selecting/Activating things in Excel is almost never necessary article, and also got your point and my code worked, that active part was unnecessary thats why I commented out. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this error if you don't try to `Select` the range (because you cannot select a range on a sheet that's inactive). One common mistake is to say "OK, well, then I'll just add a `.Activate` to make sure the right sheet is active. But that leads to spaghetti code, as you constantly need to keep track of which sheet in which workbook is active, makes the code hard to read and harder to debug.

[Selecting/Activating things in Excel is almost *never* necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?s=1%7C315.9629), and when you do it this way it tends to cause all sorts of difficult-to-troubleshoot errors, like the one you have.

```
Dim rngToFormat as Range

For x = 5 To LastRowMRPwks
    Set rngToFormat = .Cells(x, "A").Resize(1,29)
    If rngToFormat.Cells(29).Value > 0 Then 
        With rngToFormat.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 255
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    Else
        With rngToFormat.Interior
            .Pattern = xlNone
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
Next x
```